# What the difference between "arrays of parameterized type( List<String>[] )" and "array of type variable( T[] )"?

Tags: java, generics

Update: Although I have got the answer, it seems my description of the question is not very clear. So I changed a lot to make others understand my question.

---

My understanding of the reason why arrays of a parameterized type not allowed:

```java
Integer[] b = {1,2,3};
Object[] a = b;
String[] c = {"123"};
a[0] = c; // Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException
Integer i = b[0];
```

```
// Not really allowed.
List<String>[] lsa = new List<String>[10];
Object o = lsa;
Object[] oa = (Object[]) o;
List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<Integer>();
li.add(new Integer(3));
// Unsound, but passes run time store check
oa[1] = li;

// Run-time error: ClassCastException.
String s = lsa[1].get(0);
```

These two pieces of code has the same structure.

In piece 1, `Object[] a = b` makes both `a` and `b` point to the same variable `b`. So `a[0] = c` is actually changing `b`. This kind of operation won't cause any warning while compiling but will throw an ArrayStoreException.

In piece 2,`Object o = lsa; Object[] oa = (Object[]) o;` makes both `oa` and `lsa` point to the same variable `lsa`, and `oa[1] = li;`
is actually changing `lsa`.

So I think it's this reason why not allow using arrays of parameterized type.

If my understanding is right, the case like `T[] myArray` should also be rejected. Because the code below also has the same structure.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    public static <T> void test(T[] t) {
        Object[] a = t;
        String[] c = {"123"};
        a[0] = c;
        T i = t[0];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] t = {1,2,3};
        test(t);
    }
}
```

But in the Java tutorial,

```
<T> T[] makeArray(T t) {
    return new T[100]; // Error.
}
```

The reason it gives is

> Since type variables don't exist at run time, there is no way to determine what the actual array type would be.

Not the reason I expect.

It also says

> The way to work around these kinds of limitations is to use class literals as run-time type tokens

So I found an example at [Generics gotchas](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01255/index.html). The code at "The road not taken" section:

```
public class ArrayList<V> implements List<V> {
  private V[] backingArray;
  private Class<V> elementType;
 
  public ArrayList(Class<V> elementType) {
    this.elementType = elementType;
    backingArray = (V[]) Array.newInstance(elementType, DEFAULT_LENGTH);
  }
}
```

It seems using class literals already solve the problem of using array of type variable( T[] ). But the problem of the structure I mentioned at the beginning is still exist. Recall I think the structure of the three pieces of code all lead to no compiling warning but runtime error.

So, what's wrong with my understanding?

Thank you so much for your time :)

Comment: You have always been able to cast `Integer[]` to `Object[]`. This leads to ArrayStoreException, but it cannot be changed anymore (that would break existing code). This was fixed in generic collections (which were new in Java 5, so no existing code with type annotations to consider), you cannot cast `List<Integer>` to `List<Object>`. I suppose there is no backwards compatible way to fix it for arrays in the same way.

Comment: *"My understanding of the reason why arrays of parameterized type not allowed:"* ... the reason that they are not allowed by the compiler is because they are not safe.  Parameterized types are *non-reifiable*, i.e. there is less information about the type at run time than there is at compile time (because generic type information is erased during compilation).  In order for the compiler to provide the fundamental guarantee that code which compiles without errors or warnings is always type safe, arrays of non-reifiable types can not be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

---

For you first question

> why arrays of parameterized type not allowed?

I find  [the answer](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ104)

> Can I create an array whose component type is a concrete parameterized type?
>
> No, because it is not type-safe.

---

Then, I'm trying to explain  why the  example code throw exception?

1. java compile not found the problem during compile time,  each type cast look like legal. (ArrayStoreException is RuntimeException)
2. when you put a `String` element in `Integer Array`, the exception happen.
   you can use `javac` and `javap` to look into the bytecode.
   `T[] t`'s type is Object[],so variable `a` (reference type) will refer to  a `Integer[]` Object. the exception happened when you put a `String` element into a  `Integer Array`

I think the problem is not relate to java generic, so i change the example as follow to reproduce the exception.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] t = {1,2,3};
        Object[] a = t;
        a[2] = "aaa";
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the link you provide answers a lot. I misunderstanding the type check method in arrays and the effect of generics. And not the quote in your answer but the explanation of "array store check" under it clear my doubt.

Answer (score 0):

As you have found, you can't assign an element to an array of reifiable type:

```
String[] ss = {""};
Object[] oo = ss;
oo[0] = 0; // ArrayStoreException
```

This is because the type of the array element is checked at runtime, and it can be because all the type information is still available.

But with a generic array, say `List<String>[]`, the "String" bit isn't available at runtime. So, this would (notionally) work:

```
List<String>[] lss = {Arrays.asList()};
Object[] oo = lss;
List<Integer> is = Arrays.asList(0);
oo[0] = is;
```

This would work fine, because all that can be checked is that you are storing an instance of `List`.

But this would then fail if you did:

```
String s = lss[0].get(0); // ClassCastException
```

And this failure might happen far away from the assignment that caused it.

As such, generic array creation is disallowed.

---

In terms of the difference between `List<String>[]` and `T[]`: there is no difference, really. `List<String>` is a valid type for `T` to have.

The point is that you simply can't create an instance of the former: the only value a reference of that type can safely take is `null`.

> It seems using class literals already solve the problem "type variables don't exist at run time"

No, because class literals only exist for the unparameterized type: you can create an `ArrayList<String>` in this way, by passing `String.class` as the element type; you couldn't create an `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`, because there is no `ArrayList<String>.class`.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer clears some of my doubts. You said at the beginning "This is because the type of the array element is checked at runtime", so the ArrayStoreException has nothing to do with the "value copy or reference copy" thing, am I right?

Comment: What is the "value copy or reference copy" thing?

Comment: Sorry, another question. The last code example in my question. Although it throws an ArrayStoreException, but Generics is not designed to solve this kind of errors. So type erasure is the **only** reason why new T[100] and new List<String>[] are both not allowed. Is that right?

Comment: The first example, Object[] a = b make both a and b point to the same variable b, so a[0] = c is actually editing b which lead to the ArrayStoreException. I thought this is the reason why we cannot use arrays of a parameterized type.